# Do I need to upload my ios app for review in order to get publish_actions permission for my iOS game?

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to enable the users to post on facebook in my ios game. When I try to request publish_actions on facebook dashboard, it seems that I have to upload my iOS game in order to get it reviewed. Did I understand wrongly or this is indeed what the new version of facebook SDK requires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. Facebook will review that you uses the permission correctly before you are able to ask the user to grant you that permission.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have experience on uploading? My uploading finished and the UI just stopped spinning. It does not show any error but it seems not recognize my package. Btw, the package itself is 136M so I am not sure whether it hits some hidden limit or so

Comment: I work at Facebook and use to work on the team that code https://developers.facebook.com . If you don't get it to work I would suggest filing a bug at https://developers.facebook.com . Developer Support people will help you figure out what is wrong.